# TreeView Event keeps firing

Tags: c#, wpf, events, c#-4.0, treeview

I'm using the WPF version of TreeView (System.Windows.Controls.TreeView) and need to assign several events. As these are WPF most of the events are either different or behave in a different way hence my confusion as AfterExpand is not available

For now I need 2 events:

SelectedItemChanged which is at TreeView level
ExpandedEvent which is at TreeViewItem level

So far I have

```
    private void DisplayGetEventTypes(UXEvent.GetEventTypesResp resp, CustomAsyncStateContainer state)
    {

        navBarControl.Groups.Clear();

        if (resp.eventTypeItems != null)
        {
            UXEvent.EventType[] eventItems = resp.eventTypeItems;

            int nodeCount = eventItems.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
            {
                UXEvent.TryEvent eventItem = new UXEvent.TryEvent();
                eventItem.eventName = eventItems[i].name;
                eventItem.eventId = eventItems[i].id;

                NavBarGroup group1 = new NavBarGroup();

                group1.Header = eventItems[i].name;
                group1.Tag = eventItem;

                group1.IsExpanded = false;

                //Add dummy treeview to fill later if expanded
                System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeview = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeView();
                treeview.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(myTreeView_SelectedItemChanged);
                AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(myTreeView_ItemExpanded));
                group1.Content = treeview;
                group1.DisplaySource = DisplaySource.Content;

                navBarControl.Groups.Add(group1);

            }

        }
    }
```

and the following two draft event handlers for testing

```
    void myTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender,
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        // Set the data context of the text block to the selected value.
        var node = (ItemsControl)e.OriginalSource;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Selected!");

    }

    void myTreeView_ItemExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the data context of the text block to the selected value.
        var node = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Opening! - " + node.Header);

    }
```

The problem I'm having is that `myTreeView_ItemExpanded` is firing multiple times when any treeviewItem is expanded. I think it fires multiple times due to the event bubbling .

Firstly, can anyone point me to some good resources where I can read up on this behaviour?

Secondly, how can I amend my code to make `AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(myTreeView_ItemExpanded));` a single event only?

Thank you

Comment: Basically, you want which event to fire once only? The ItemExpanded or SelectedItemChanged?

Comment: Yes, the `myTreeView_ItemExpanded` fires multiple times and I only want it to fire once. SelectedItemChanged is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted the problem. The line

`AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(myTreeView_ItemExpanded));`

should read

`treeview.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(myTreeView_ItemExpanded));`

I assume the first line must have added the event handler to all available controls and all fired when the event triggered.